# Move file from temporary folder to uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

In my WordPress the visitors can upload files like `texts` and this files go in this path
`C:\xampp\htdocs\www\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\temporary`, After validating I need to insert this files in this path `C:\xampp\htdocs\www\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2014\10` like attachment , Should I using `wp_insert_attachment` or `wp_handle_upload()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is related to wordpress because I do not have a slightest idea about it. But in php, you use the [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function to copy a file from one folder to another. And if you want to remove the file from the temporary folder, you are looking for the [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function for deleting a file

Comment: I can't do it like this because I need it in the media library of WordPress